# What time is it in a Kubernetes pod?

Tags: .net, kubernetes

Say I have some (.NET Core) code running in a k8s pod and I ask for:

```
DateTime.Now
```

I assume I will get the date-time from the host that the pod is running on. Is there any way of getting a date-time value that is consistent across the k8s cluster?

Comment: "Is there any way of getting a date-time value" - how about `DateTime.UtcNow`?

Comment: Note that DateTime.UtcNow will take time zones out of the picture, but if the various systems in the cluster have clocks set slightly differently, you'd still see skew. I'd expect most k8s clusters to have synchronized clocks though, so there'd be minimal skew.

Comment: @Paul Suart - ...that is consistent across the cluster? That is, the same time value should be returned if the call is made in any pod running on any host. What if one host is set to daylight saving and another isn't?

Comment: @Jon Skeet - is clock synchronisation something I have to configure, or is Kubernetes helpful enough to do that for me?

Comment: I don't know, but searching for "kubernetes clock sync" gives a lot of hits that would be good research...

Comment: As @JonSkeet says, you're still relying on each "pod" having its time set correctly.  I was being slightly facetious, I admit, but getting the UTC time is going to be a better bet than the local time.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - that is useful, thank you. I did search earlier for variants on 'kubernetes coordinate clocks' and got none of those results.

Comment: regarding clock drift in Minikube on Mac: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/1378

Answer (score 11):

The clock in a container is the same as the host machine because it’s controlled by the kernel.

The timezone is controlled by the OS layer tho and so may be different in the container. You can mount in the time zone file to overcome this.

Synchronization of clocks across machines is a complicated topic. You can go as simple as installing an NTP client on all the nodes or as complex as installing GPS hardware clocks on every node.

If your Kubernetes nodes are VMs this adds another layer of complexity. Most IaaS and hypervisors provide some way of synchronizing the VM clock with the host, but you still need to keep all your host machines in sync.