# How to change TimeZone of entire Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, timezone

I want to change timezone of our entire on-prim kubernetes Cluster from default UTC to America/Los_Angeles.

I am aware about changing it for single deployment by using volumes[ref.: https://evalle.xyz/posts/kubernetes-tz/] This is tedious job to do, as there are many pods in my cluster.

I am looking out better option to do it for entire cluster one go. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR**: You will not be able to globally set the TZ in a cluster.

Based on the answer of “*KarlKFI*” in ([What time is it in a Kubernetes pod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48949090/what-time-is-it-in-a-kubernetes-pod))

> The clock in a container is the same as the host machine because it’s controlled by the kernel.
>
> …

As you already mentioned, you can change the TZ of the POD by binding the `zoneinfo` of the host OS.

So the **TIME ZONE** (TZ) is something that is locally controlled at  POD level  and can’t be changed globally because this should be done within the POD definition.

If you want to change the TZ without binding the `zoneinfo` of the host OS, based on (https://serverfault.com/questions/683605/docker-container-time-timezone-will-not-reflect-changes) you may change it by setting the TZ environment variable. If you change your image and set the TZ  environment variable in there, when the POD is created it will inherit from the image so the POD will be created with the TZ environment variable set.

So your only options are:

**1.-** Bind the `zoneinfo` of the host OS in each POD.

**2.-** Change your TimeZone on each node of your cluster.

**3.**- Set the TZ environment variable on your ***IMAGE*** so the POD will inherit the value when is created.

Comment: https://evalle.xyz/posts/kubernetes-tz/ is now a dead link

Answer (score 4):

It can be easily done by using [k8tz](https://github.com/k8tz/k8tz), a kubernetes admission controller and a CLI tool to inject timezones into Pods that can be installed on the cluster using Helm.

```
helm repo add k8tz https://k8tz.github.io/k8tz/
helm install k8tz k8tz/k8tz --set timezone=America/Los_Angeles
```

After it's installed, any pod created on the cluster will be mutated by k8tz admission controller to make sure the timezone is explicitly set to `America/Los_Angeles`. You can choose a different timezone for different namespaces or pods using the `k8tz.io/timezone` annotation.

DISCLAIMER: I am the author of k8tz.

Answer (score 1):

I am using command on deployment.yaml and works fine:

```
 image: myregister/my-image:latest
        command: ["dpkg-reconfigure"]
        args: ["tzdata"]
```

This command set UTC.I think that you cab use a command to set America/Los_Angeles

Answer (score 0):

You can set the timezone of the cluster using deploy.yaml file. Add the following lines according to your requirement:

```
volumes:
    - name: tz-config
      hostPath:
        path: /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Prague
```

[Here is an article with more details](https://evalle.xyz/posts/kubernetes-tz/)

Comment: I have mentioned the URL about doing it on single deployment. I am looking out if any solution to do it on all the pods instead of adding this Volumes parameter one by one all the pods.

Comment: @ronshine you can use pod-preset for same

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @armando You will not be able to globally set the TZ in a cluster.
You can use a `pod preset` and predefine a timezone.
Use that pod preset in your pod.
This method is somewhat similar to (https://evalle.xyz/posts/kubernetes-tz/) but this will be a little easier at the time of pods creation.
Checkout [podpreset](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/podpreset/).

Answer (score -1):

What article describe is how to pass `localtime` to **POD**, not a cluster. POD's are ephemeral, and yes you can use **kubectl patch**, or adding some kind curl call to API to provide the same patch to apply these changes. But you better to change all configs for pods if you want to pass and keep this info in all your deployments.